# iPhone : Problem while integrating wordnik API in my app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have implemented wordnik API in my sample app.

Its working great in sample.

But when I try to integrate it with my app. It is unable to set its `Client config`.

What should I need to do ?

Comment: Have you set the API_KEY properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste the error message, and indicate whether or not you're using the Wordnik UI components or just the data SDK.  That'll make it easier to troubleshoot.